How to create a macro that calls run() on every element in enum
I have an enum that contains elements with structs that all implements trait with run() function and the next function have to call run() on every element

pub struct Cli {
    #[command(subcommand)]
    pub subcommand: Commands,
}

pub trait Runnable {
    fn run(&self);
}

#[derive(Subcommand, Debug)]
pub enum Commands {
    Save(save::Save),
    Keys(keys::Keys),
    Remove(remove::Remove),
    //...
}

// generated code should be like that
// or impl Commands { fn proceed() }

pub fn proceed(cli: &Cli) {
    match &cli.subcommand {
        Commands::Save(cmd)   => cmd.run(),
        Commands::Keys(cmd)   => cmd.run(),
        Commands::Remove(cmd) => cmd.run(),
        //...
    }
}

It should generate the last function when adding attribute-like macro #[generate_run_calls].
I tried to do this but with no result. I have error: expected type, found $ with note: this error originates in the attribute macro generate_run_calls
// lib.rs

#[proc_macro_attribute]
pub fn generate_run_calls(_attrs: TokenStream, item: TokenStream) -> TokenStream {
    let input = parse_macro_input!(item as ItemEnum);

    let expanded = quote! {
            impl $enum {
                pub fn proceed(cli: &Cli) {
                match &cli.subcommand {
                    $enum::$variants(cmd) => cmd.run(),
                }
            }
        }
        #input
    };

    return TokenStream::from(expanded);
}


https://docs.rs/enum-dispatch?

Don't use $ with quote!, use #. And you need to get what you want from input (enum, variants, etc).
